# Vector<unsinged char> Transformation to String and Back

Tags: c++, sqlite, vector

I'm trying to:

1. vector to string
2. Convert this string to const char*
3. Insert it to the database column of type `VARCHAR(8192)` **without** text or blob binding
4. Read it from database
5. Convert this string to vector

Result vector must be unchanged from the one inserted on 1.

Minimal Reproducible example:

```
vector<unsigned char> from = {'\200','a','\30'};
std::string result = from.to_string(); // Our function for converting to string
vector<unsigned char> to = vector<unsigned char>(result);
    //You need to have table "some_table" with column "value" for this to work
    //Insert result to database
    std::string sql =
        "INSERT INTO some_table ('value') VALUES ('"+result.c_str()+"')";
    int rc = sqlite3_exec(m_Db, sql, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
    // Select value from database
    rc += sqlite3_prepare_v2(m_Db,"SELECT value FROM some_table",
                            -1, &stmt, nullptr);
    if (rc != 101 && rc != 0) {
        LOG_F(INFO, "Failed to get the value");
    }
    sqlite3_step(stmt);
    vector<unsigned char> read_result = ConvertToVector(std::string(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0))));
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
//Read Result need to be same as from
```

Result should be same as vector from so: {'\25','a','\30'}

I would be glad for a solution that is effective, fast and universal.
Possibly don't use encoding to UTF-8 etc. because this can be a problem for some user databases.

How to do this properly?

Comment: You can use a loop for example.

Comment: First step: convert to a utf-8 encoded string/vector/array of chars. Utf-16 works too.

Comment: @eerorika can you show example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way to do this is to use **base64** encoding and decoding.

Its commonly used and will work without blob_binding.

Withdraw of this, is a performance penalty.

Comment: I would also look into using a 7bit encoding rather than base64, which would compress the data 17% more.

Comment: What will happen if you have long array of unsigned char? This is an example on 3 unsigned chars but what if I have 1024 of them in vector, how it would compress data by 17%? Can you explain, please?  I will be glad if you answer this question with your idea, and example of encoding. Thank you

Comment: If the vector has 1024 `unsigned char`, then converting that to base 64 will result in a string with 1366 characters.  Converting it to a 7 bit encoding would only need 1170 characters. But it also occurs to me, that as long as you're always use the same compiler/settings/OS, then you can actually use the full 8 bits, for a string with 1024 characters.

Comment: I made an input_iterator that safely bypasses the undefined behavior to preserve all 8 bits: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5315a7f296b65793.  Note: This will look funny in the string, since the bytes aren't all visible characters, and it will look funny in the database, which will probably reencode the string as UTF8 or something, but it's valid and safe regardless.

Answer (score 2):

Both `std::string` and `std::vector` constructors have an overload that takes a beginning and an ending iterator of a sequence that define the contents of the new string or vector. And both `std::string` and `std::vector` can supply the beginning and an ending iterator of their own:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> from = {'\200','a','\30'};
std::string result{from.begin(), from.end()};
std::vector<unsigned char> to{result.begin(), result.end()};
```

Comment: This is not the fastest way, to do this and can't be done without bind_blob function in SQLite iam searching for way to just concat string to INSERT SQL Request without binding

Comment: Are you familiar with the term "SQL injection"? That's what happens when you "concat string to INSERT SQL Request without binding". For more information, see https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: This has nothing to do with sql injection, maybe it could be done with encoding chars as integers and padding them all to 3 places  (000-255) and then decoding this by 3 places as chars back into vector

Comment: I explained why this is useless, I need to insert the string into the database if you try to create a string of characters of \20 \50 \200 etc. it will most certainly not work because std::string is not made for handling unsigned chars and c_str() will output corrupted memory from this string. The best solution to do this is to convert it to the base64 and then store it. Your answer is basically copy-paste you didn't read the question at all. Try to run example that you provided, you didnt even tried to run your own suggested code.

Comment: @JiriOtoupalイりオトウパー: That's a little aggressive. The memory isn't "corrupted", it's merely interpreted differently. But the bits are exactly the same.  Converting to base64 will be much slower. But: The conversion to `unsigned char` to `char` is undefined behavior, so you do have a point.

Comment: Conversion from unsigned char vector to string (which has chars) is undefined behaviour, thus code from answer will produce an invalid string. Sorry for sounding a bit aggressive, but it's pathetic that this invalid answer got 2 upvotes when it's useless and will be misleading to other people that will actually need to solve this problem. Please provide a better solution if base64 appears to be slow. I will appreciate it.

Comment: No, it's not undefined behavior. What was asked is: "I'm trying to transform vector to string and this string to vector without losing any data". Using the two constructor overloads will do that. You are welcome to come up with some vector of unsigned chars that, after executing the round-trip conversion as shown in the code, to `std::string` and back to `std::vector`, results in a vector that does not compare equal to the original one, using the `==` operator overload. No data will be lost with the shown transformation. Even `'\0'` chars will be converted correctly.

Comment: Please try to run the code you had posted, and try to insert result to the SQLite database. Look what's inside your suggested string.c_str() and try to insert 5 of them. Then look into the database and compare the inserted string with actual string. Even with blob binding, it will not work. So instead of arguing please test it.

Comment: The original question already had a minimal reproducible example, the first three statements. And replacing them with the three statements that I provided results in the original vector, exactly as is. The End. As far as how to store arbitrary blobs in some database, that's a completely different question, that has absolutely nothing to do, whatsoever, with converting a vector to a string, and back and forth. MySQL has an appropriate data type, just for that. No need to convert anything to a string. And as far as downvoting your question, that's someone else.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik It is indeed undefined behavior to cast values between signed and unsigned if the values are out of range, actually. Jiri Otoupal イり オトウパー is correct.  Though one can make an input_iterator that bypasses this safely: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5315a7f296b65793

Comment: @JiriOtoupalイりオトウパー: The database not having the string you expected does not mean it's corrupted.  The code is almost certainly working fine, despite undefined behavior.  However, the database is probably reencoding the string, it's not corrupted, it's just switched encodings.

Comment: The question that was asked was how to convert `std::vector` to `std::string` and back, without losing contents. This is how it's done. P.S. @Mooing, as of C++17, signed/unsigned conversions are defined behavior, and this is guaranteed to return the original value, when converted back. Have a nice day.

Comment: @MooingDuck unfortunatelly database never gets right string due to undefined behavior and thus even if database just reencoded the string you will get in some examples just 30 Chars out of 120

Comment: @JiriOtoupalイりオトウパー: Well if you have a buggy database that's corrupting valid strings, than that's an entirely different problem.  As Sam pointed out, there's no undefined behavior here. This answer is correct.

Comment: C++17: `[conv.integral] A prvalue of an integer type can be converted to a prvalue of another integer type ... the result is the unique value of the destination type that is congruent to the source integer modulo 2^N , where N is the width of the destination type.` -- the ellipsis bits are not germane. Both chars and unsigned chars have the same width. The conversion is, effectively, mod 256 going both ways. Most C++ compilers have done this for decades, C++17 simply formalizes existing practice.

Comment: MySQL's `blob` datatype is explicitly designed for storing binary data. At $dayjob$ we store oodles of stuff like gzipped tarballs, etc, in there. PDF files. Use bind variables and blob columns. The End.

Comment: @MooingDuck when SQLite 3 is corrupted and buggy what cross platform sql databse would you use ? Im open to a suggestions.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik in question i explicitly said **without blob binding**

Comment: All that "blob binding" does is have the mysql client library correctly quote and escale the bound variable's contents, as a replacement for the `?` placeholder. That's all it does. You are of course welcome to do so yourself, but I see absolutely no point in doing so, except as creating a breeding opportunity for bugs. This is what bind variables are for. And, I do see that the shown SQL does fail to properly quote the string, and opens up an SQL injection attack. The correct solution is to always use bind variables, this is what anyone in Information Security will tell you.